# Converting closest values to a fixed value in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, data-manipulation

I would like to convert closest values of a column (col2 in the below) to the same value (say the largest one). Suppose the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],"col2":[1,5,6,10,12,14,17]}) 

     col1  col2
0     0     1
1     1     5
2     2     6
3     3    10
4     4    12
5     5    14
6     6    17
```

Given column col2 and a closeness threshold of 2: difference of 5 and 6 less than threshold, so both will be the same, i.e. 6. Values 1 and 17 are far away from the rest of values in col2, so no changes there. Differences between 10, 12 and 14 are less than 2, so change them all to 14. (why I need this process: when converting image to text using pytesseract.image_to_data, the top coordinates of text are slightly different and I want to fix those coordinates and make them same values.)

The final output given col2 and closeness threshold of 2 will be:

```
     col1  col2
0     0     1
1     1     6
2     2     6
3     3    14
4     4    14
5     5    14
6     6    17
```

You help much appreciated!

Comment: Rephrase your question. It is not clear. Looking at the output versus the input, you seem to want  to group by bins of intervals of 5 and find the largest in each bin. If thats the case, then we could try `df.groupby(pd.cut(df['col2'],[0,4,9,14,19,24], labels=[1,2,3,4,5]))['col2'].transform('max')`

Comment: Thanks wwnde: what I am looking is, in fact, grouping similar values to a fixed value (largest one). Say, 10, 12 and 14 would be all 14. value 17 is far away from all the rest, so no changes, the same for value 1. 5 and 6 are close together, so both will be 6.

Comment: what's the closeness tolerance value

Comment: closeness tolerance value is 2 here, as an example, but in a real case of converting image to text data, I have a closeness tolerance value of 5.

Comment: Thanks wwnde: hope it is enough clear.

Comment: do you mean a tolerance of between 1 and 2, because how does 5, turn into 6?

Comment: value in next row minus value in current row <=2 (i.e. 6-5<=2), then replace current value with the next one. The same for 12-10<=2, 14-12<=2. I saw shift function and it might work here, but how? df["col"].shift(-1)-df["col"]<2.

Comment: Your logic doesnt work because 1-5 will also be less than 2, apears to me the between logic will. If it doesnt present other situations where that may result in a wrong replacement and I will see how to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values are sorted like in sample data use:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(df['col2'].diff(-1).abs().le(2)).bfill()
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     0   1.0
1     1   6.0
2     2   6.0
3     3  14.0
4     4  14.0
5     5  14.0
6     6  17.0
```